# Convert cprofile from python3 to python2

Tags: python, python-3.5

I want to analyze the performance of my python program, I'm used to do it with runsnakerun, unfortunately it does not support python3..
Is there a way to convert it to python2? or have runsnakerun work with python3?

I've tried other profilers, like snakeviz.. but they don't work well..

Any other good profilers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Take a look at http://www.pyvmmonitor.com/

Comment: did not seem to work for python3